# React-Native Expo send Firebase post when users close the application

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I've currently got post routes which send user locations, and isOnline: true when the app is open, when the user closes the app I'd like to update the regular data and also update isOnline: false to my Firebase Realtime DB. I tried to play with console logs to figure out exactly when the unmount occurs, but it's not consistent enough for me to tell. Maybe I'm wrong about how the componentWillUnmount works!

(If this is a duplicate question, I'm very sorry. I looked for about an hour before I decided to post this)

This is my Unmount:

```
componentWillUnmount() {

    this.userDisconnectHandler();

    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);

    this.stopTimer();
  }
```

This is my disconnectHandler:

```
userDisconnectHandler() {
    var postDataRef = firebase.database().ref(`live-data/${userName}`);
    console.log("disconnected")

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        postDataRef
          .set({
        coordinate: {
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        },
        userName: `${userName}`,
        isOnline: false,
          })
          .then(() => console.log("finalPostComplete"))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      },
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

Comment: You may want to try app state `https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate`.

Comment: @SaachiTech Post this as a solution so I can give you credit for solving it

Comment: Posted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try AppState https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

According to doc

> AppState can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background,
> and notify you when the state changes.
>
> AppState is frequently used to determine the intent and proper
> behavior when handling push notifications.

that should fit in your case.